# Competition for Jobs: Different types of applicants as balls in urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say there are two type of (unemployed) workers, denote them with $h$ and $l$. There is a measure 1 of unemployed workers, and $P$ denotes the share of $l$-types. These get on average $H_l$, $H_h$ many job offers. Since they can only take one job (at random), that means that they reject job offers with probability $1/H_l$ and $1/H_h$.

**You** are an unemployed person of say type $h$. You are at a vacant job together with $X$ many applicants (including you), out of which $X_h$ are of type $h$. The company does not discriminate by types, it randomly offers the job to someone. If they refuse, it offers the job to the next one, etc.

**What is the probability of you getting the job offered?**

---

I think the solution should be

$$ \sum_{x_h = 0}^{X-1} \bigg[hyper(x_h, K = X_h, N = X)\cdot(1-\frac{1}{H_h})^{x_h} \cdot \sum_{x_l = 0}^{X-1-x_h} hyper(x_l, K = X-X_h, N = X)\cdot(1-\frac{1}{H_l})^{x_l}\bigg]$$

where $hyper(\cdot)$ is the hypergeometric distribution.

Is this correct? I'm trying to go through all the possible "this is how many other people will be offered the job before you, times their rejection rate".

Is there a neater way to do express this? I'll want to numerically solve this later on and with all these nested sums that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me whether you want the probability the person will be offered the job, or the probability the person is offered the job and also accepts it. I'll choose the first interpretation. If you want the second instead, just multiply the result by $\frac{H_h -1}{H_h}$.

For simplicity, assume the company organizes the applicants randomly into a line, and then goes down the line offering the job each person in turn until one of them accepts, surely wondering about all the dunderheads who showed up even though they are not interested.

Since the order is random, your chance at being person $k$ in line is $1/X$. You will be offered the job only if every person in front of you turns it down. The probability of a person other than you turning down the job when offered is $$q := \frac {X_h-1}{X-1}\frac 1{H_h} + \frac {X_l}{X-1}\frac 1{H_l} = \frac1{X-1}\left(\frac{X_h-1}{H_h} + \frac{X_l}{H_l}\right)$$ Given that you are the $k$th person in line, the probability of you being offered the job is $q^{k-1}$. Thus the total probability you are offered the job is the sum over all $k$ of the probability that you are $k$th in line, and are offered the job in that position: $$\sum_{k=1}^X \frac1X q^{k-1} = \frac1X \frac{1 - q^X}{1 - q} $$

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but to me it seems like you're doing this "with replacement", as $q$ is a function of the total shares in the pool only, $X_h$ and $X_l$, and independent of whether other people before have refused it. That's why my expression is so messy, because I try to compensate for that. I have a rough guess, but to be sure: What exactly is your argument for making $q$ independent of $k$?

Comment: The definition of $q$ has nothing to do with $k$. It is simply the probability that a random person, when offered the job, will turn it down. The probability that you at $k$ are offered the job is the probability that those $k-1$ people before you all turned it down. These are independent events. The choice of person $j$ to accept or not does not depend on what anyone else chose to do. If it helps, consider the company cruelly continuing to offer the job to everyone, and telling any later "yes" answerers "too bad". A valid offer to you requires each previous to answer "no".

Comment: Actually, there is a modification that needs made: $q$ does not include you, so it should be $$q = \frac1{X-1}\left(\frac{X_h - 1}{H_h} + \frac{X_l}{H_l}\right)$$